# How to make a 3D mesh invisible in Godot?

Tags: godot

Just like the title says i'm trying to make the mesh disappear after a set value reaches zero. Current code is trying to simply turn the entity invisible so that later i can implement a resurrect function.

```
if Sname == get_node("Entity").get_name():
    print("punched number 1")
    selected.health = selected.health - 10
    if selected.health <= 0:
        selected.health = 0
        get_node("Control/Button").disabled = true
        $Entity.visable = false
```

Is it even possible to toggle that value or is there an easier way to do this?
I dont want to use free_queue() as that would interfere with other entitys.

Thanks for the help in advance, im new to Godot so sorry if this ends up being a no brainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set [`$Entity.visible`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-property-visible), not `$Entity.visable`.